# JSON dictionary lookup

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a difficult dictionary to search in:

```
{'results': 
      {'opensearch:itemsPerPage': '1', 'artistmatches':
                {'artist': [{'streamable': '0', 'image':
                        [{'#text': 'http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/34s/d593a102f004491689bc7e07d8fb09ba.png', 'size': 'small'},
                         {'#text': 'http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/64s/d593a102f004491689bc7e07d8fb09ba.png', 'size': 'medium'},
                         {'#text': 'http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/174s/d593a102f004491689bc7e07d8fb09ba.png', 'size': 'large'},
                         {'#text': 'http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/d593a102f004491689bc7e07d8fb09ba.png', 'size': 'extralarge'},
                         {'#text': 'http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/d593a102f004491689bc7e07d8fb09ba.png', 'size': 'mega'}],
                        'listeners': '3251959', 'name': 'Michael Jackson'}]}}}
```

Now I am trying to get the value with key = '#text' with the biggest size possible (Mega if possible).

Is there an easy way to loop through this dictionary or do I need to use a lot of for loops?

Comment: Would there be multiple `artist` entries, or are you only looking at the first?

Comment: @MartijnPieters there will be more artist entries but I'm only searching for the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a dictionary with relative ordering:

```
sizes = ('small', 'medium', 'large', 'extralarge', 'mega')
sizemap = {size: value for value, size in enumerate(sizes)}
```

Use that map with the `max()` function to find the maximum image size for a given `artist` entry:

```
for artist in data['results']['artistmatches']['artist']:
    image = max(artist['image'], key=lambda i: sizemap[i['size']])
    image_url = image['#text']
```

Demo (with `data` bound to the dictionary specified in your question):

```
>>> for artist in data['results']['artistmatches']['artist']:
...     image = max(artist['image'], key=lambda i: sizemap[i['size']])
...     image_url = image['#text']
...     print(image_url)
...
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/d593a102f004491689bc7e07d8fb09ba.png
```

Comment: ♦ Nice! What does the lambda do?

Comment: @DriesCoppens: tell `max()` how to extract the value to maximise on. So for every dictionary in `artist['image']`, the value to maximise is the translation of the `'size'` key via the `sizemap` dictionary. So `'size': 'mega'` in an image dictionary is translated to `4`, which is higher than any of the other mapped sizes.